# Django templates indentation in Emacs

Tags: django, templates, emacs, elisp

I'm using django-html-mumamo-mode in order to manage Django templates in Emacs. Unfortunately, I've searched over the net but didn't find any way to change the HTML indentation from 2 to 4, when this mode is activated.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try customizing the variable `django-indent-width`, for example by adding this to your .emacs file:

`(setq django-indent-width 4)`

Comment: What about changing the indent width for `django-html-mode`?